# Point that optimizes radial homogeneity of a measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$, absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure. For any point $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$, define a function
$$f_x:S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
(viewing $S^1$ as the set of directions in the plane) $f_x$ as the rate at which the ray out of $x$ in direction $\theta\in S^1$ is sweeping out mass (as measured by $\mu$), as $\theta$ changes. In other words,
$$f_x(\theta) = \frac{d}{d\theta}\int_{C_\theta}\mu,$$
where $C_\theta$ is the cone with vertex $x$ and bounded by a ray parallel to the positive real axis and a ray in direction $\theta$ from $x$.

Because $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure, it seems to me that $f_x$ will be well-defined and continuous from $S^1$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and therefore it will attain a maximum on $S^1$. Denote this maximum by $m(x)$. This gives us a map $m:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $x\mapsto m(x)$.

It seems to me that $m$ is continuous (again, by absolute continuity of $\mu$ with respect to Lebesgue measure, although I don't quite see how to prove it and maybe it's false). Also, $m\to \infty$ as $x\to \infty$, because there exists a bounded set with positive mass with respect to $\mu$, and the angle needed to sweep out this set will go to 0 as $x\to \infty$, so the rate at which angles sweep out mass as it goes over this set must grow unboundedly as $x\to \infty$.

It follows that $m$ attains at least one minimum.

I would like to know:

- Is this minimum necessarily unique?
- Is there a simple formula for where it is attained? For example, I would love it if it's attained at $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} x d\mu$, the center of mass, but this seems too good to be true.

Thanks in advance.

**Addendum 9-24-21:** I think that the center of mass does not in general minimize $m$. I am imagining a measure with a thin, homogeneous horizontal strip of mass to the left of the origin, centered at $-K$, say, and a thin vertical strip of the same length, width and density, centered at $+K$. Then the origin is the center of mass, but the two strips don't contribute equally to the maximum of $f_0$: the one to the left, being horizontal, will be traversed by a ray out of the origin in much less angle than the one to the right. Thus, $m(0)$ is totally determined by the strip on the left, and $m(x)$ is lowered by moving $x$ leftward from the origin.